# Second Preimages on n-bit Hash Functions by John Kelsey and Bruce Schneier

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, 2nd-preimage-resistance

I read your https://www.schneier.com/academic/paperfiles/paper-preimages.pdf

And found there:

---

```
«3.2 A Generic Technique: Multicollisions of Different Lengths»
```

---

```
    «Finding a Collision on Two Messages of Different Lengths.»
```

---

```
        «ALGORITHM:»
```

---

```
            «Steps:»
```

---

THIS:
"Build lists A and B as follows:"

```
– for i = 0 to 2n/2 − 1:
• A[i] = F(hin,M(i))
• B[i] = F(htmp,M(i))
```

There «i» takes value from 0 to 2^(n/2), BUT numbers of M’s blocks much less «2^(n/2)»
Maybe correct go through the cycle [0, 2^k] ? Otherwise, many of M(i) simply don’t exist.

or I'm wrong and something i don't understand?

P.S. Is there a chance, that won't find a collision in a range [0, 2^k]?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, i figured out. I thought "M" - original message, but it's random data necessary for generation "Expandable Messages". In this case, range [ 0, 2^(n/2) ] is right.

Comment: If you answered your own question, would you mind taking it out of the comments and submitting (and accepting) it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i figured out. I thought "M" - original message, but it's random data necessary for generation "Expandable Messages". In this case, range [ 0, 2^(n/2) ] is right.